# Trying to execute a list of Cypher statements in Neo4j via the admin interface

Tags: neo4j

I have a file that contains a long list of Cypher statements, something like:

```
create (n:oeuvre {ide12:"41",numpers:[87603],titre:"JE PARS"});
create (n:oeuvre {ide12:"151",numpers:[395225,364617,396308,306762],titre:"I DID IT FOR LOVE"});
create (n:oeuvre {ide12:"67",numpers:[54001],titre:"GRAND PERE N AIME PAS LE"});
create (n:oeuvre {ide12:"80",numpers:[58356],titre:"MON HEURE DE SWING"});
create (n:oeuvre {ide12:"91",numpers:[58356],titre:"AU QUATRIEME TOP"});
```

When I drag my file on the Cypher admin console area "Drop a file to import Cypher or Grass" and then click on the little play icon, I get the message "Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 1405".

Is there a way to batch execute Cypher requests via the admin console? The wording "Drop a file to import Cypher" seems to suggest so.

Thanks

Yann

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, the console just let's you run one statement at a time.  Fortunately a statement can have multiple `CREATE` clauses, so if you just remove the semi-colon characters it should work.

Alternatively you can use the `neo4j-shell` command with the `-file` argument to run a cypher script file.  This method allows for scripts with multiple commands separated by semi-colons.

Comment: The latter is recommended for such large imports