# Having issues executing a cypher query generated from graphgen

Tags: neo4j

I am using this tool : http://graphgen.graphaware.com/#/ to try to generate mock data for testing purposes. But the .cql file it generates shows errors in neo4j desktop. The first error shows this:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 91
```

I removed all the semicolons according to this answer: [Trying to execute a list of Cypher statements in Neo4j via the admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628204/trying-to-execute-a-list-of-cypher-statements-in-neo4j-via-the-admin-interface)

It then shows this error:

`Invalid input 'C': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 1 (offset: 65))
"CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (media:Media) ASSERT media.neogen_id IS UNIQUE"
 ^`

i try removing the constraints by deleting the first three lines but it shows another error: `WITH is required between SET and MATCH (line 42, column 1 (offset: 1945))
"MATCH (s1:User {neogen_id: 'b085096ddc66811c2fc0ebe3e6b77ccb27a2e8cb'}), (e1:Media { neogen_id: '33420bcccdf7395f4d341b3480058c1aae01e3be'})"`

Here's the file in a gist embed:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/scroobius-pip/466bc41f4c0597c9578821b2f73b7050.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell tools should be able to run the script as is with the semicolons.

Try executing with `cypher-shell`, located in the bin folder of your installation.